# How to create HAR(Hadoop Archive) from Java?

Tags: hadoop, har

I do rest-service which must create har-files in hadoop cluster. This rest works on application server, not in hadoop cluster. I use org.apache.hadoop.tools.HadoopArchives for this. But I don know how to set cluster when I create HadoopArchive object.

HadoopArchives har = new HadoopArchives(conf);

On the other hand, when I try to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell, I use next

FsShell shell = newShellInstance();

conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://...");

shell.setConf(conf);

And every thing works well.

But I don't undestand how do the same HadoopArchives.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe your question has noting to do with rest. Can you please provide more information about what you are trying to do with HAR, what files you archive?

Comment: There are some files in HDFS. I want to put them into har-file. And I want to do it from the rest or from the another kind of java application. But last one isn't run as hadoop jar ... This run on application server as usual application. I don't know how set conf for new HadoopArchives(conf).

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to run `hadoop archive` command as an external process (with `ProcessBuilder` for example), and passing your configuration as `HADOOP_CONF` environment variable.
Otherwise you will have to write a MapReduce job and directly start it from your rest service, which will be convoluted. `HadoopArchives` is essentially a command line utility, and not designed to be used as a library.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! If it possible can you get simple example how to run hadoop archive with ProcessBuilder and how use HADOOP_CONF in this case. I don know how send my configuration as HADOOP_CONF. In my case conf consists from "fs.defaultFS" plus Kerberos settings. How object conf send as HADOOP_CONF?

Comment: You won't be needing `Configuration` as an object, `Configuration` reads files from `HADOOP_CONF` when its created, now you just pass `HADOOP_CONF`. If case you don't have `HADOOP_CONF`, you need to create it or download it from you cluster (CDH and HDP have pages where zip archive of it can be downloaded)

Comment: Obviously i'm a loser ) I don't undestand two things. 1. Rest works on non hadoop server. If use ProcessBuilder for running hadoop archive, how "say", that this command should be running on hadoop cluster. 2. HADOOP_CONF is set of files (conf/core-site.xml,conf/hdfs-site.xml,conf/mapred-site.xml,conf/yarn-site.xml)? I need create or download them to the rest location, correct them (set kerberos settings). Right? But how send them as HADOOP_CONF environment variable? Sorry for my stupid questions but I standing at a crossroads and don't now what to do. Thank you for your answers and patience.

Comment: It seems you have to setup the machin where your REST service in running as an edge node. There are other options of course, you can submit a job which does archiving, you can do it through rest https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_Submission